# React-Native custom npm start script in xcode

Tags: javascript, xcode, react-native, npm

Hi all I'm trying to have multiple custom start scripts in my package.json for my React-Native app and I can't figure out how to actually get the custom start scripts to kick off during the build in xcode.  Obviously I can run them manually in the terminal every time but how do I get xcode to bundle and run

npm run start-custom vs npm run start?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a shell script under `Build Phases` in your project.

Ref: https://medium.com/@ankitkumargupta/xcode-add-build-phase-shell-script-without-cluttering-your-project-file-2de8aa3fe0ce

Comment: I guess more of what I am trying to do is figure out how to get the bundler to run a specific npm command to switch between dev and production.  Any ideas on that?  Adding into the build stages doesnt seem to do anything other than launch the metro bundler.